# Can I make an Xcode project read only, ie prevent it from modifying files?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6, readonly

I'm working on an iOS project that I edit in Emacs but debug in Xcode. I occasionally edit the source files in Xcode accidentally, so I'd like to prevent that. I can't make the files themselves read only, since I need to edit them. Is there any way to make the Xcode editor treat them as read only and prevent me from editing them?

I do occasionally use Xcode to edit the *project*, e.g. adding and removing files. It's just Xcode's *file editor* that i want to prevent from editing files. So, I'd need something that applies to the file editor only, or that can be easily toggled on and off.

Comment: What's wrong with editing files in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the source folder readonly permissions for your GUI login user and read-write permissions for some other user you just use for terminal/emacs sessions.

---

Edit:

Comments:

> i use my emacs to do lots of other things that i want to keep doing as
>   my normal user, though. i also occasionally do want Xcode to edit the
>   project, e.g. adding and removing files. it's just Xcode's file editor
>   that i want to prevent from editing files.

Okay then lets flip my solution: Run Xcode as a different user that only has readonly access:

```
!#/bin/bash
su readonlyuser
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

And then use emacs from your normal session. If you need Xcode to have readwrite access you'll need to quit it and re-open it normally. It's a pain but I can't think of any way around it besides some sort of nifty menu bar app that toggles the permissions on the folder to give your readonlyuser write access. You should also give the readonlyuser readwrite access to the xcodeproj bundle and any other Xcode project metadata.

To make this a little less ugly you could wrap that bash script in an AppleScript or Automator Action, export it as an application, and give it the same icon as Xcode but with a little indicator so you know it's the readonlyuser one. Then you can stick it in your dock or whatever.

Comment: interesting idea! i use my emacs to do lots of other things that i want to keep doing as my normal user, though. i also occasionally do want Xcode to edit the _project_, e.g. adding and removing files. it's just Xcode's _file editor_ that i want to prevent from editing files.

Comment: this could definitely work! quitting and restarting back and forth when i need to add files isn't ideal, but it's probably tolerable. i'll have time to try it out tonight; i'll keep you posted.

Comment: ah, i missed the idea of giving the readonly user r/w access to xcodeproj but not the source files. this sounds perfect!

Comment: I'm actually kind of liking the menubar app idea rather than having to kill Xcode - it just needs a little switch and on toggle runs a bash script to recursively change permissions on the entire folder. I might mess around with that tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Just open terminal and lock source file.

```
chmod a-w source_folder
```

Here is youtube screencast: http://youtu.be/tB-BhqlDAdE

Works exactly like what you expected !

Comment: sorry, no, i mentioned in the question that this won't work for me. i need to be able to edit the files outside of xcode; i want _only xcode itself_ to be unable to edit them.

Comment: old thread but a great idea. I often open multiple projects with only one being the editing target. So long as you can stay focused, it is fine, but it is very easy to edit non-target files. If there was a global "hold down the Option key" kind of approach to lock an entire project, that would be so idea. 

I simply shunt my non-target Xcode instances over to visually remind me, but that sucks when you are distracted.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not have a readonly browsing mode!

To prevent yourself from accidentally modifying files:

1. Create a disk image of your project directory by using the Disk Utility.
2. Mount the disk image file.
3. Open the project from the disk image file.

This way you can't accidentally modify your original source files while browsing them with Xcode.